# Problems running Flask Web App on linux Debian using Gunicorn and Nginx

Tags: python, nginx, debian, gunicorn, wsgi

So I'm currently trying to put my Web App online using Flask, Debian 9, Gunicorn.
The problem I'm having, after typing > gunicorn wsgi:app :

```
[2019-11-15 12:22:11 +0000] [11643] [ERROR] Exception in worker process
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/root/testing/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/arbiter.py", line 583, in spawn_worker
    worker.init_process()
  File "/root/testing/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 129, in init_process
    self.load_wsgi()
  File "/root/testing/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/workers/base.py", line 138, in load_wsgi
    self.wsgi = self.app.wsgi()
  File "/root/testing/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/base.py", line 67, in wsgi
    self.callable = self.load()
  File "/root/testing/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 52, in load
    return self.load_wsgiapp()
  File "/root/testing/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/app/wsgiapp.py", line 41, in load_wsgiapp
    return util.import_app(self.app_uri)
  File "/root/testing/venv/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/gunicorn/util.py", line 350, in import_app
    __import__(module)
  File "/root/testing/wsgi.py", line 1, in <module>
    from __init__ import app
  File "/root/testing/__init__.py", line 44, in <module>
    create_app()
  File "/root/testing/__init__.py", line 24, in create_app
    from .models import User
ValueError: Attempted relative import in non-package
[2019-11-15 12:22:11 +0000] [11643] [INFO] Worker exiting (pid: 11643)
[2019-11-15 12:22:11 +0000] [11639] [INFO] Shutting down: Master
[2019-11-15 12:22:11 +0000] [11639] [INFO] Reason: Worker failed to boot.
```

My wsgi.py:

```
from __init__ import app

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app.run()
```

My **init**.py:

```
# init.py

from flask import Flask
from flask_sqlalchemy import SQLAlchemy
from flask_login import LoginManager 
from flask_bootstrap import Bootstrap

db = SQLAlchemy()

def create_app():
    app = Flask(__name__)
    Bootstrap(app)

    app.config['SECRET_KEY'] = 'secretkey'
    app.config['SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URI'] = 'sqlite:///db.sqlite'

    db.init_app(app)

    login_manager = LoginManager()
    login_manager.login_view = 'auth.login'
    login_manager.init_app(app)

    from .models import User

    @login_manager.user_loader
    def load_user(user_id):
        return User.query.get(int(user_id))

    from .auth import auth as auth_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(auth_blueprint)

    from .main import main as main_blueprint
    app.register_blueprint(main_blueprint)

    if __name__ == '__name__':
        app.run()

    return app

create_app()
```

My models.py:

## models.py

```
from flask_login import UserMixin
from . import db

class User(UserMixin, db.Model):
    id = db.Column(db.Integer, primary_key=True) # primary keys are required by SQLAlchemy
    email = db.Column(db.String(100), unique=True)
    password = db.Column(db.String(100))
    name = db.Column(db.String(1000))
```

Note: All indepencies are installed in my virtualenv, I've tried using gunicorn with only this code:

```
from flask import Flask
app = Flask(__name__)
@app.route('/')
def hello_world():
    return "Hello World!"
if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True,host='0.0.0.0')
```

And that worked perfectly fine.

Comment: You never import from `__init__`, you import from the package. But most likely `__init__.py` should be something like `app.py` and then you would import `models` without the dot.

Comment: @KlausD.Thanks for the reply. I tried this and ended up with an ImportError: No module named db. This is refering to line 4 in models.py

Comment: Same there, do the same import as for models.

Comment: Could you clarify that a little bit, because `from . import db` is importing a database file. So how would that be done then like with the models?

Comment: Just `import db`.

Comment: I changed every import that had a . and changed the `__init__` to `__app__`, deleted the create_app function.
Thanks for your help @KlausD.

Answer (score 0):

I changed every import that had a . and changed the **init** to **app**, deleted the create_app function.